# how to install chart marked as development via helmfile

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helmfile

i'm trying to install a chart marked as "development" via helmfile but getting a 'Release name is invalid' error. I can find this chart using helm search repo --devel but apparently there is no such flag in helmfile. Could someone please help me with this?

my helmfile looks like so:

```
repositories:
  - name: chartmuseum
    url: myurl

helmDefaults:
  atomic: true
  wait: true
  timeout: 960
  cleanupOnFail: true
  historyMax: 3

releases:
  - name: "chartmuseum/myapp"
    namespace: "team-1"
    createNamespace: false
    chart: "chartmuseum/myapp"
    version: "23.2"
    values:
      - "./variables.yaml"
    installed: true
```

Comment: What is the actual error?  The version `23.2` isn't a "development" semantic-version number.

Comment: the error is "release name in invalid" while trying to install this

Comment: The `name:` probably shouldn't have a slash in it.  The `chart:` would though.